# Typescript and ng-include in angular 1.3 not working

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am using  controllerAs syntax with ng-include, and this is the layout.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm" ng-include src="'partial.html'"></div>
```

This is the partial View.

```
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">{{vm.title}}</div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

My issue is, if i set the title in the MainCtrl's constructor, it's showing up correctly in the partial view. But if i set it in a button click event, then the binding doesn't work. The title doesn't show up. What could be wrong ?

```
class MainController implements IMainController {
    public title :string; 
    constructor() {
        this.title = "Test";// this works.
        }
    }

    public setTitle(): void {
        this.title = "New Test"; this does not work !
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: From the docs, it looks like when you use `ng-include` as an attribute, you don't use `src`. Try `ng-include="'partial.html'"`

Comment: Also, where is your button? Seems to work fine over here ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/y7ThYvay5fL0CGYJgBoN?p=preview

Comment: You must have write `ng-click="vm.setTitle()"` on html to work it